# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure asp.net.Core3.1 when Use app.UseStaticFiles

Tags: asp.net, iis, publish

I Have Restapi with the asp.net core3.1
I want to upload Image with any problem when use of the this code (File is Folder for image)

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Files")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/Files")
        });
```

In vs2019

But when publish project. I have error  HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
when I remove the above code, publish project work correctly
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

First please check if ANCMV2 is installed, If the target machine you are deploying to doesn't have ANCMV2, you can't use IIS InProcess hosting.

In addition, to enable inprocess hosting, the csproj element AspNetCoreHostingModel is added to set the hostingModel to inprocess in the web.config file. Also the web.config points to a new module called AspNetCoreModuleV2 which is required for inprocess hosting.

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```